# How to change the cell color in php based on the given date

Tags: php, css, sql, colors

I have a sql table that compare today's date and the Expiry_Date of the item for three different cases and display the relevant message for each case, and I am trying to change the color for each cell regarding to the identified case.

For example,

Case1: if today's date> Expiry_Date the cell color should be Red

Case2: if today's date = Expiry_Date the cell color should be Yello

Case3: if today's date < Expiry_Date the cell color should be Green

I have added the below code, but only the case3 is being executed, and also gives a green color (wrong color) for other cases

So is there anyway to change the cell's color according to its case?

My code

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    ID,
    Item_Name,
    Expiry_Date,
    CASE 
        WHEN `Expiry_Date` < CURDATE() THEN CONCAT (`Item_Name`, ' has EXPIRED already')
        WHEN `Expiry_Date` = CURDATE() THEN CONCAT(`Item_Name`,' is going to expire today')
        WHEN `Expiry_Date` BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN CONCAT(`Item_Name`,' will expire tomorrow')
        WHEN `Expiry_Date` > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN CONCAT(`Item_Name`,' has not expire yet')
        ELSE 'Error processing expiration date.'
   END AS `Expiration_Message`
FROM
    test;";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{      
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Item_Name']. "</td>";
    if($row['Expiry_Date']<['CURDATE()']) //  green
            echo "<td style='background-color: #00FF00;'>".$row['Expiry_Date']."</td>"; 
    else if($row['Expiry_Date']>['CURDATE()'])//  red
            echo "<td style='background-color: #FF0000;'>".$row['Expiry_Date']."</td>"; 
    else if($row['Expiry_Date']==['CURDATE()']) //  yellow
            echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFF00;'>".$row['Expiry_Date']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['Expiration_Message']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnUkn.png)

Comment: do you know about date('Y-m-d', strtotime($somedatetocheck))?

Comment: Ronnie answer will do the work

Comment: Thanks Anil, just wondering why people down vote it, while it may be the answer.. Or at least leave a comment why the down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case1: if today's date> Expiry_Date the cell color should be Red

Case2: if today's date = Expiry_Date the cell color should be Yello

Case3: if today's date < Expiry_Date the cell color should be Green

**Code:**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Item_Name'] . "</td>";
    if(strtotime($row['Expiry_Date']) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))) //  green
    {
        echo "<td style='background-color: #00FF00;'>" . $row['Expiry_Date'] . "</td>";
    }
    else if(strtotime($row['Expiry_Date']) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))//  red
    {
        echo "<td style='background-color: #FF0000;'>" . $row['Expiry_Date'] . "</td>";
    }
    else if(strtotime($row['Expiry_Date']) == strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))) //  yellow
    {
        echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFF00;'>" . $row['Expiry_Date'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . $row['Expiration_Message'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Try this.

`date('Y-m-d', strotime($row['Expiry_Date'])` will convert your `$row['Expiry_Date']` to a `Y-m-d` format. `date('Y-m-d')` checks current (server/client, not sure, think its client) date.

Comment: Thanks for your helping, I tried that code but nothing has changed, all the Expiry Date cells are still in green

Comment: Can you var_dump $row for me? I need to know if your query is right.

Comment: **Is it var_dump ($result) ?** because I am getting
 `object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(9) ["type"]=> int(0) }`
 **or var_dump ($row['Expiry_Date'])?**, because I am getting _NULL_ for this case

Comment: It is `<pre> <?php var_dump($result); ?> </pre>` (it would be echo `$row['Expiry_Date']`, do you see the difference between var_dump and echo?). I see you have no expiry_date in your $result array, which means your database request is not correct. Please change your query to something like: $sql = "SELECT 
    ID,
    Item_Name,
    Expiry_Date,
FROM
    test;"; let me know the results ;)!

Comment: Sorry I did not get your point, the _Expiry_Date_ is already there in the sql query

Comment: join this chat room. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158845/how-to-change-the-cell-color-in-php-based-on-the-given-date

Comment: I should have 20 reputation to talk there, but I do not have

Comment: Sorry Mr Ronnie, I saw your message but I cannot reply since I do not have enough reputation

Comment: Mr Ronnie, sounds good haha. Alright, we'll continue here. Let's delete some comments in future, those which are not relevant. What I mean: Change your query to the one which i wrote, and see which results you get in $results variable. Can you check this for me and copy paste it into a comment? Currently it looks like the variable $results has not the information you need to display the correct dates.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned before, the _Expiry_Date_ is already there in the sql query and everything is showing as expected in that table

Comment: var_dump($result); shows you `object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(4) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(9) ["type"]=> int(0) }` right? doesnt seem `Expiry_date` is within in, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right, but how to do that since the `Expiry_date` is in the sql query already ?
Another question, why you only interested in showing `Expiry_date` while the others are not there also such as `Item_Name`. Sorry my php background is not that good

Comment: Can you var_dump($row); for me? No problem, let's debug your issue, we will get an answer. But as i don't know your code I need to help you debugging based on the information you give. Let's start at the beginning, which is debugging. $results doesnt give the information, so var_dump $row, think the information is inside that one. But I need to make sure before we continue.

Comment: Thanks for your patient :)  `var_dump($row);` is giving `NULL`

Comment: Anytime. So that means your query is not right, otherwise you would have items in $row, $row should give information. Did you var_dump $row in your while statement? otherwise it's always empty. So like this: (piece of code:) `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{      
var_dump($row);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID']. "</td>";`. Does `$row['Item_Name']` give information btw?

Comment: `array(8) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(4) "Milk" ["Item_Name"]=> string(4) "Milk" [2]=> string(10) "2017-10-25" ["Expiry_Date"]=> string(10) "2017-10-25" [3]=> string(24) "Milk has EXPIRED already" ["Expiration_Message"]=> string(24) "Milk has EXPIRED already" }` and the same thing for other items

Comment: Great! See my edited answer, and try that. I've changed it.